# File downloading strange issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saved the document file/pdf file or txt file in the database. Now to get that File I am using the code below.

```
JobApplicantResume oApplicantResumne = new JobApplicantResume();
DataSet dsApplicantResume = oApplicantResumne.GetJobApplicantResumeByJobApplicantResumeId(1552);//1552 Long value
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/xx-xxxx";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dsApplicantResume.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sFileName"].ToString());
//Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dsApplicantResume.Tables[0].Rows[0]["binFile"];
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

It is giving the exact file. No problem is there to open the file.

In some other page I used the same code:

```
JobApplicantResume oApplicantResumne = new JobApplicantResume();
DataSet dsApplicantResume = oApplicantResumne.GetJobApplicantResumeByJobApplicantResumeId(1552);//1552 Long value
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/xx-xxxx";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dsApplicantResume.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sFileName"].ToString());
//Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dsApplicantResume.Tables[0].Rows[0]["binFile"];
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

It is also giving a file to download. But when I open it the data are coming in some different format.

Like:

```
؟½ï؟½ï؟½ï؟½ï؟½ï؟
```

Junk data. I could not understand why the problem is coming. If any one faced this similar kind of issue or any suggestion / help will be very much helpful to overcome this problem.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: It is a bit late now. However, are u able to solve it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add Unicode Byte-Order-Mark [full example](http://www.jinweijie.com/asp-net/add-utf-8-signaturebom-at-the-start-of-response-file/).

```
    //add the BOM
    byte[] bBOM = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF };
    byte[] bContent = ms.ToArray();
    byte[] bToWrite = new byte[bBOM.Length + bContent.Length];

    //combile the BOM and the content
    bBOM.CopyTo( bToWrite, 0 );
    bContent.CopyTo( bToWrite, bBOM.Length );

    //write to the client
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( Encoding.UTF8.GetString( bToWrite ) );
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```